# Unexpected token illegal on Ajax get

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am sending dynamically generated sql through ajax
And i am getting `parsererror - Error:reportDataFunction was not called - ERROR123- reportDataFunction`

And i am getting this error  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in google chrome console.

And this with that error:

```
http://MYWEBSITE/webService/myService.asmx/myServiceDB?callback=reportDataFunction&userName=dskrbic&procedureName=declare+%40result+xml+SET+%40result+%3D(SELECT+unitCode+AS+unitCode+FROM+unit+WHERE+universityCode+%3D+144+FOR+XML+path%2Croot%2CELEMENTS+XSINIL)DECLARE+%40outputValue+nvarchar(MAX)+EXECUTE+convertJSONPMulti+%40result%2C+%40outputValue+output+SET+%40outputValue+%3D%27selectView+%3A%27%2B%40outputValue+SELECT+%27%7B%27%2B+%40outputValue+%2B%27%7D%27&_=1459259972547
```

This is my procedure i am calling :

```
 var procedureVal = "declare @result xml SET @result =(SELECT unitCode AS unitCode FROM unit WHERE universityCode = 144 FOR XML path,root,ELEMENTS XSINIL)DECLARE @outputValue nvarchar(MAX) EXECUTE convertJSONPMulti @result, @outputValue output SET @outputValue ='selectView :'+@outputValue SELECT '{'+ @outputValue +'}'"
```

This is my ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    url:"URL",
    data: { userName: "dskrbic", procedureName: procedureVal },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "reportDataFunction",
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + ' - ERROR123 - ' + "reportDataFunction")
    }
});
```

If i paste my procedureVal directly in query in sql or if i call it directly through webService if i go to link of my webService i get result back but if i call it through ajax i get error. And this is example of what i get :

```
({selectView :[    {\"unitCode\":\"1\"},    {\"unitCode\":\"2\"},    {\"unitCode\":\"3\"},{\"unitCode\":\"4\"}]});
```

Any idea where is the problem ? Thank you for your help

EDIT :

My headers of GET 
[image: My headers of GET]

And this is what my response looks like :

reportDataFunction({selectView :[    {\"unitCode\":\"1\"},    {\"unitCode\":\"2\"},    {\"unitCode\":\"3\"} .....

From first " The response is red , i supose there is error around there ?

Comment: Well what is the actual response when you try the request via ajax? Check the browser developer console.

Comment: @Pointy Except i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

There is nothing much else there except of link adress for Get , Which i will add to main post

Comment: The "unexpected token" error may be coming from an invisible Unicode character. If you cut-and-pasted code from a website, that can happen. It can be hard to find those errors; what line of code is the error on?

Comment: @Pointy The code was retyped by me multiple times .
Line of code ? Please be more precise , i just get that error on ajax call , also that ajax works fine with other procedures i call , only with this SQL i get error

Comment: If you're getting that error on the ajax call, and not on page load, that means the error is with the returned text. That's why you need to look in your browser's developer console so that you can see the actual HTTP response contents.

Comment: @Pointy I have opened it in mozila now , and this is what i get 

SyntaxError: illegal character            myServiceDB:1:38

Comment: OK, and *what does the HTTP response look like*? That's where the error would be.

Comment: @Pointy I have added it to main post up there "And this with that error" part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107651/discussion-between-noitse-and-pointy).

Comment: Depending on the browser you're using, there'll be a "Network" tab in the developer console. When your ajax call happens, you'll see a GET request show up there. You can then look at the response headers and the response content. Exactly how depends on the browser, but it will be something like what I described.

Comment: @Pointy Updated main question

Comment: Ah, OK.  I think the problem is simpler than I thought: you're trying to do a JSONP request to a service that just returns plain JSON.

Comment: @Pointy I tought about that as well , i changed from dataType jsonp , to json , but still got same error , or is it something else i am forgeting ?

Comment: You *can* do cross-domain JSONP requests, but you cannot do cross-domain JSON (normal ajax) requests unless the server explicitly allows it via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers (commonly called "CORS Headers").

Comment: @Pointy So i should enable Access-Control-Allow-origin in my webConfig of webService ?

Comment: Yes, if you have control over the service. There are SO questions about how to do it and plenty of stuff on the net in general if you google around for it.

Comment: Ok i am going to try to make that  , thank you for your time :) i will let you know the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason i wasnt able to send this part of sqlQuery

```
SET @outputValue ='selectView :'+@outputValue SELECT '{'+ @outputValue +'}'"
```

So i have split it in 3 pieces , and made procedure that has that part , and i am sending generated values to that procedure , where i put them together and execute as one